# should I unmount this for partition?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

Please tell me how can I complete partition process. I also tried KDE partition manager but it doesn't show resize option.

[image: in image /dev/sda1 & /dev/sda3 are locked]

How can I unlock or is it safe?

Comment: You can only resize partitions that are not in use: you should do this from the live session and not directly from ubuntu. If you already do: unmount the partitions. And seriously: NEVER do disk operations without the power supply.

Comment: but I want to do partition of </dev/sda3>. Is it possible or safe?